# Microphone does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, xna

In reference to [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827802.aspx).  The assembly, `microsoft.xna.framework.dll`, has been added to the references and I'm using the namespace `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio`, however I receive an immediate error on the first step, shown below:

```
Microphone [error 1] mic = Microphone.Default [error 2];
```

> **Error 1:** The type or namespace name 'Microphone' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> **Error 2:** The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context

According to the MSDN article, I've added the necessary references (or if other references are necessary, they aren't listed), so I'm unsure why I'm getting the first error.  I would assume the second error occurs because of the first error.

Comment: are you copying the dll to the build output directory?

Comment: Which is your platform? Maybe you are working on Windows 8, and Microphone class is not allowed on it.

Comment: @pinckerman Yep, I'm on Windows 8.  That explains it.

Comment: You should include that Windows 8 tag and remove "c#:" from the question's title, it's already in the question's tags.

Comment: @user1306322 I've added it, but someone rejected my edit.

Comment: @pinckerman reviewers these days... Can't wait to get enough rep points to be able to make instant edits.

Comment: @user1306322 LOL totally agree, that will be a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Windows 8, `Microphone` class is not allowed on it, so you need to change your code, using `MediaCapture` class instead.
[This page](http://rushabh.azurewebsites.net/?p=137) could be useful to you.

Comment: That's not so important, it only explained that you can't use Microphone class. Try searching on MSDN website if you need info about MediaCapture.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subscribe to an event by specifying an event handler that does not exist.
This event handler, in the form of a method generally (though you can do this with anonymous delegated and so on) must be present, and match the signature defined by the event.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the reference to the assembly, you need to declare the namespace by adding a `using` statement at the top of your file, or explicitly declare the namespace at every usage.
For example:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
```

OR

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone mic = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone.Default;
```

Comment: Yeah, in the beginning I use **using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;** which adds it to the program.  Even if I type out *Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone mic = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone.Default;* in the program, it still generates the same error for Microphone (not the rest).