# The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context. getting this error when opening an unity(version 5.6.0f3) project is visual studio 2017 in window 8.

[RequireComponent (typeof (AudioSource))]
public class SingleMicrophoneCapture : MonoBehaviour 
{

```
    //A boolean that flags whether there's a connected microphone
    private bool micConnected = false;

    //The maximum and minimum available recording frequencies
    private int minFreq;
    private int maxFreq;

    //A handle to the attached AudioSource
    public AudioSource goAudioSource;
    public AudioClip recordedAudioClip;
    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioClip myAudioClip;
    //public Text fileExist;
    bool startRecording = false;

    public Sprite[] recordingSprites;
    public int count =0;
    //int recordedFileCount =0;
    public bool isDefaultAudioPlaying = false;
    [SerializeField]
    public Sprite[] playSprites;
    public GameObject forwardButton;
    public GameObject backwardButton;
    public GameObject playButton;
    public GameObject replayButton;
    //Use this for initialization
    public AudioClip[] allAudioClips;
    public string storyName;
    float[] samples;
    public Dictionary<int,float> recordedClipDict;
    void Start() 
    {
            //ReplayButtonClicked ();
        //Check if there is at least one microphone connected

        recordedAudioClip= null;
        if(Microphone.devices.Length <= 0)

            {
            //Throw a warning message at the console if there isn't
            Debug.LogWarning("Microphone not connected!");
        }
        else //At least one microphone is present
        {
            //Set 'micConnected' to true
            micConnected = true;

            //Get the default microphone recording capabilities
            Microphone.GetDeviceCaps(null, out minFreq, out maxFreq);

            //According to the documentation, if minFreq and maxFreq are zero, the microphone supports any frequency...
            if(minFreq == 0 && maxFreq == 0)
            {
                //...meaning 44100 Hz can be used as the recording sampling rate
                maxFreq = 44100;
            }

            //Get the attached AudioSource component
            goAudioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
          // mainAudioSource = Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        }

    }
```

how to solve this.

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870199/microphone-does-not-exist-in-current-context

Comment: i visited the link u provide but i am not getting any solution from there and again i post this to get a solution

Comment: The solution in there suggest to use MediaCapture instead of Microphone.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー: This is not a pure C# project, but a Unity project, with its own [Microphone](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) class.

Comment: right, is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you using a platform that do not support the [`Microphone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) API. One of the platforms that do not support the [`Microphone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) API is the [WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-audio.html). There might be other platforms other than [WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-audio.html) without Microphone support.

Switch to a platform that supports the [`Microphone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) API from the *Build Settings*.

You can also use Unity's [preprocessor directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) to guard it and make sure that the [`Microphone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) API is **not** used when using platforms that do not support it or did not implement it.

```
#if !UNITY_WEBGL
//YOUR Microphone CODE HERE
#endif
```

If you really need Microphone in WebGL with Unity, make a plugin or use [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/microphone-webgl-library-79989) one(Not free).

Comment: Actually the project is on android unity. Now i want the html files from my project, switching the platforms to WebGL from build setting. after switching to WebGL  gettting this Microphone error. Is there any other process to get HTML files from my project ?

Answer (score 0):

We can not see your using statements.

But it seems like your are missing

```
using UnityEngine.AudioModule;
```

Comment: I am using these statements 
 using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;  
using UnityEngine.UI;   
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

Comment: In Unity 5.6, the `Microphone` class is defined in the `UnityEngine` namespace [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Microphone.html)

Comment: i used the statement using unityEngine;  but still showing the same error